# CORS Filter in RESTEasy

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have created a CORS filter that adds the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to responses from the server, following the entry in [the link](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1781/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-cors-on-rest-how-to-make-rest-apis-accessible-from-a-different-domain/).

My Application class has many singletons, and I have added the filter as one of those singletons:

```
singletons.add(new RESTCorsResponseFilter());
```

But the filter is never called.  Where am I suppose to put it? My server is created in code as follows:

```
public class AppServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
    //context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setContextPath("/api/v1.0");
    ServletHolder h = new ServletHolder(new HttpServletDispatcher());
    h.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.domain.services.Application");

    context.addServlet(h, "/*");
    server.setHandler(context);
    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

How can I make that filter work? Where am I suppose to place it to register it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to register it as a provider.  Did you annotate it `@Provider`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Is that all it takes? I have annotated it provider, and I extended the ContainerResponseFilter interface, but it never gets called.

Comment: What version of things are you using? How are you deploying this?

Comment: I am using JBoss-AS-7.1.  Do I need to add something to the web.xml file for it do automatically recognize the filters and add them when they are annotated with @Provider?

Comment: I ended up switching to Wildfly, and then I added the filter class as a filter in the web.xml file and it worked. Thanks for your pointers!

Comment: Sorry, missed your response.  The article you cited is for JAX-RS 2.0.  If you implemented it verbatim from that site, it won't work on AS7.1.